# Because of different networks, the fork lifters are not following the paths

Tags: anylogic

what would be the best idea to follow if the nodes are not in the same network?
I have Source and destination nodes in different networks. when the fork lifters pick the item from the source Node and process the item, store it in Storage and later retrieve it to drop at the destination for the shipment.
Because of different networks, the fork lifters are not following the paths.

Answer (score 0):

If you work on the same `Level`, you ideally should connect your networks (just draw a path between them).

If your networks are on separate levels, use the "[Lift](https://anylogic.help/markup/lift.html)" block. This will allow agents to move across networks on different levels.

PS: If you are on the same level but do not want to connect networks manually, you could use a trick where each of your networks is put on a separate `Level`, you give the levels the same height and use the "Lift" blocks.